# how can we merge csv as column side by side using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have three CSV files:

file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv

Each CSV file has a first column (A) containing values as below:

file1.csv

```
A  
asd  
zxc  
qwe
```

file2.csv

```
A  
iop  
jkl  
bnm
```

file3.csv

```
A  
rty  
fgh  
vbn
```

How can we horizontally merge these files into a single file with the columns as below:

merge.csv

```
A   B   C   
asd iop rty   
zxc jkl fgh  
qwe bnm vbn
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Read files
data_1 = pd.read_csv(file1.csv)
data_2 = pd.read_csv(file2.csv)   
data_3 = pd.read_csv(file3.csv)   

# Assuming the name A for the first column of each csv is not a typo
data_2.rename(columns={'A': 'B'})
data_3.rename(columns={'A': 'C'})

# Order columns
new_columns = []
for i in range(len(data_1.columns):
    new_columns.extend([data_1.columns[i], data_2.columns[i], data_3.columns[i]])

# Concatenate dataframes
data_out = pd.concat([data_1, data_2, data_3], axis=1)

# Reorder columns
data_out = data_out[new_columns]
```